# Nginx Ingress controller scaling issue Intermittent 502

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a GKE cluster with 3 services(1 pod each) exposed via an Nginx ingress controller (1pod). There's a client certificate-based authentication setup for the ingress controller. While running the JMeter test I am only able to reach 10tps and I am receiving 502 error from the Nginx server intermittently.

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.10</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The CPU, Memory and Disk Utilization seems fine
[image]

When the services are exposed as a Loadbalancer, the JMeter tests gave me 250tps. I read a couple of Nginx blogs and I got only two options - to scale vertically or horizontally. I understand that the nginx will be doing SSL offloading but I want them to take at least 200tps.

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Probably your nginx-controller or service is overloaded and can't manage the requests. Please share the ingress spec and tell a little bit more about the service you are testing.

Comment: I am using the default nginx config: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Comment: OK, but how about your ingress file? Could please share the yaml?

Comment: you can have the nginx ingress controller deployed as a daemonset, I would recommend using this approach